# Unit Testing OAuth Login with Cake 2.3

Tags: unit-testing, cakephp, oauth

I need some advice on how to set up a unit test in Cake 2.3 that tests OAuth login. I'm using the [thomseddon/cakephp-oauth-server](https://github.com/thomseddon/cakephp-oauth-server) plugin. Note: I've reviewed examples such as [CakePHP 2.3 - Unit testing User Login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15750135/cakephp-2-3-unit-testing-user-login), but I'm still confused about how exactly to approach an OAuth test using the plugin. Any help appreciated.

The following is what I currently have in my unit test. Not very much of a test, yet.

```
/**
* testOAuthLogin method
* Tests that OAuth login works
* @return void
*/
public function testOAuthLogin(){

    $data = array(
        'response_type' => 'code',
        'client_id' => getenv('THREE_SCALE_APP_ID'),
        'User' => array(
            'username' => TEST_USERNAME,
            'passwd' => TEST_PASSWORD
        )
    );
    $result = $this->testAction('/oauth/login', array(
        'data' => $data, 
        'method' => 'post'
    ));
    debug($result);
}
```

This returns:

```
{"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"No client id supplied"}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to figure this out. I just needed to setup up proper fixtures for User and AccessToken. And then I had to ensure that these were imported in the controller that I was testing in via $fixtures.

Example of my AccessTokenFixture:

```
<?php
App::uses('OAuthComponent', 'OAuth.Controller/Component'); 
/**
 * AccessTokenFixture
 *
 */
class AccessTokenFixture extends CakeTestFixture {

/**
 * Fields
 *
 * @var array
 */
    public $fields = array(
        'oauth_token' => array('type' => 'string', 'null' => false, 'default' => null, 'length' => 40, 'key' => 'primary', 'collate' => 'utf8_general_ci', 'charset' => 'utf8'),
        'client_id' => array('type' => 'string', 'null' => false, 'default' => null, 'length' => 36, 'collate' => 'utf8_general_ci', 'charset' => 'utf8'),
        'user_id' => array('type' => 'integer', 'null' => false, 'default' => null),
        'expires' => array('type' => 'integer', 'null' => false, 'default' => null),
        'scope' => array('type' => 'string', 'null' => true, 'default' => null, 'collate' => 'utf8_general_ci', 'charset' => 'utf8'),
        'indexes' => array(
            'PRIMARY' => array('column' => 'oauth_token', 'unique' => 1)
        ),
        'tableParameters' => array('charset' => 'utf8', 'collate' => 'utf8_general_ci', 'engine' => 'MyISAM')
    );

/**
 * init method
 * @return void
 */
    public function init() {
        $this->records = array(
            array(
                'oauth_token' => OAuthComponent::hash('SAMPLE_ACCESS_TOKEN'),
                'client_id' => 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID',
                'user_id' => 1,
                'expires' => 1367263611232323,
                'scope' => ''
            ),
            array(
                'oauth_token' => OAuthComponent::hash('SAMPLE_ACCESS_TOKEN'),
                'client_id' => 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID',
                'user_id' => 2,
                'expires' => 13672640632323323,
                'scope' => ''
            )
        );
        parent::init();
    }

}
```