# Unit testing CakePHP 3.x Basic Authorization Login

Tags: unit-testing, cakephp, basic-authentication, cakephp-3.0

I want to test the workings and functionality of the basic CakePHP 3.x Authentication form, and the associated logic behind that action. However, I have gone round and round trying to write a unit test for the login page generated with CakePHP 3.x - you know, for completeness of code coverage - and have found available information seriously lacking or absent.

I can find plenty of information for unit testing the login form on CakePHP 2.x, which is mostly useless because of the changes between CakePHP 2.x & 3.x. Can anyone point me to some **detailed information** regarding, or provide an explanation of, testing the **login page**?

**EDIT** I am ***not*** looking for tutorials (but not gonna turn them away if the expose requested info), tools, or other shortcuts; I don't want/need a copy & paste solution. What I am looking for is more info about the data structures so that I can put a unit test together.

**EDIT 2** I am attempting to accomplish [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15779232/549510) but with CakePHP 3.x instead.

Comment: SO isn't ment for asking for tutorials, tools, etc... please make your question about a specific programming related problem. Also please make it clear whether you are really using Basic authentication, as "_the login page generated with CakePHP_" sounds more like Form based authentication.

Comment: @ndm I have added some clarification to my question, thank you for pointing out the bit of ambiguity in my original question. If needed, I can add some code to the question when I'm back at my workstation; though code should not be needed as I'm asking about the default, baked implementation.

Answer (score 4):

Check this out!

```
public function testAddUnauthenticatedFails()
{
    // No session data set.
    $this->get('/articles/add');

    $this->assertRedirect(['controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'login']);
}

public function testAddAuthenticated()
{
    // Set session data
    $this->session([
        'Auth' => [
            'User' => [
                'id' => 1,
                'username' => 'testing',
                // other keys.
            ]
        ]
    ]);
    $this->get('/articles/add');

    $this->assertResponseOk();
    // Other assertions.
}
```

Copied from [Cake 3 cookbook on testing](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/testing.html#testing-actions-that-require-authentication)

**EDIT:**

Didn't realize that the question was about testing of the interns of the Authentication - but here's a link for that: https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/tree/master/tests/TestCase/Auth

Comment: Thats a great suggestion @Spritz, thank you. However, I am looking for specific information on how to test the action involved in the authorization login form itself, not the authentication protection of the basic auth system in CakePHP.

Comment: Oh! I'm terribly sorry for that :-D Then you should look here: https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/tree/master/tests/TestCase/Auth

Why would you test such thing though? In my experience it's better to focus on lower code coverage - and instead make some good tests :-) Don't focus too much on the percentage ;-)

Comment: Thanks again @Spritz! Please add the link into your answer so that I can give it a proper upvote! The resource you provided will definitely help me out in other areas, as I'm a bit foggy on TDD and unit testing. Something I am aiming to fix with my current project. However, not exactly what I am looking for; I have have updated my question with a better illustration of my goal.

Comment: I also used a very simple test suite to test login functionality: https://github.com/dereuromark/cakefest/blob/3.0/tests/TestCase/Controller/AccountControllerTest.php#L47